# Setting up home WiFi hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, windows-10, adapter, setup

I’m try to set up a home WiFi hotspot using my PC as the access point.

The USB adapter is installed and working and the PC is connected to the PC via a USB cable to a phone (tethering).

I setup the network with:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myssid key=mykey
```

and it works fine. but when I try to start it I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

I’ve tried to reinstall the adapter, roll back drivers, use Windows drivers, change power management and pretty much everything else I could find on Google.

EDIT:
I now fianlly managed to get a connection to the wifi hotspot i created. However i cannot get internet access. The host computer is setup to allow internet (ICS) and says internet is available, however on the connected devices (in my case a tablet) i get limited internet.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show hostednetwork

Hosted network settings
-----------------------
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "lukewifi"
    Max number of clients  : 100
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : 52:e3:27:9c:ea:46
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Channel                : 11
    Number of clients      : 0
```

i can connect to this network but any device connected doesnt get internet.

EDIT
my ipconfig

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : luke
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TP-LINK Wireless PCI Express Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-E3-27-9C-EA-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 15:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-E3-27-9C-EA-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Internet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : PdaNet Broadband Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-37-BD-39-42
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.19.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 01 January 2016 09:05:02
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 02 January 2016 18:27:34
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.19.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.19.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 52-E3-27-9C-EA-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.198.231(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5BCB937F-8E0D-467E-9B22-AD49111BEB63}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D5A49A77-B044-4930-BDC1-F78745383ECE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2896:67a9:43e2:5ac9(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2896:67a9:43e2:5ac9%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 436207616
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-35-8E-64-90-2B-34-AD-63-EE
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork

Comment: proposed edit for formatting; the secret is using the {} button for "code". If you enabled Connection Sharing, `IP Routing Enabled` should be yes, so that's where your problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I enabled routing. Problem still remains

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to share your PC's internet connection to a mobile, but unable to use it via wifi adapter. Try doing it via USB.

For more information check here
[for android](http://www.howtogeek.com/117118/how-to-connect-your-android-to-your-pcs-internet-connection-over-usb/)
,[for windows](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/how-to-share-internet-over-usb-from-pc-to-a-windows-phone-8-device)

Comment: I now have the device connected wireless to my pc. However i get limited internet. I have shared the internet to my wireless network (hotspot) but any connected device does not get any internet access.

Comment: @Mystic Can you add a snapshot so I can explain it clearly.

Comment: To share your internet connection, go to the Network and sharing center and click on Change adapter setting. Here right click on the Connection that you use to connect to the internet and select properties. In properties go to Sharing tab and check the box "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection and select the network connection name that is used by your hotspot.(For this check the Network Connection Window and look for Connection which says Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter). And save it. Now your internet connection is shared.

Comment: i posted my ipconfig, sorry about the formatting, cant get it to format on this site.